# g++: error: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/lclasses12.zip: Java compiler not installed on this system

Tags: c++, oracle11g, g++4.8

I was trying to compile cpp code which try to establish connection with oracle db. Everytime i got this error
 g++:error:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/lclasses12.zip: Java compiler not installed on this system.
The command which am i executing is given below-
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++  -L $ORACLE_HOME/lib/* -L $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/* cpp_db_conn.cpp
 Although when i check java version and javac version i got this
 **java -version**
 java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

**javac -version**
javac 1.8.0_121
 I don't understand why it's not able to find java compiler on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it.g++ was trying to find gcj(java-compiler embedded with g++) which was missing.So installed it externally using this command-
`yum install libgcj 
yum install java-1.5.0-gcj-devel`